# Creating NSData from live audio stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsurl

I want to capture a part of live audio stream into a NSData file. I tried simply creating a NSData, but my application always stucks and NSData line, because source is continous. Is there any other way to create, an NSData or some array of ints from the internet radio signal?

```
RadioInfo *sharedRadio = [RadioInfo sharedRadio];
NSString *program = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sharedRadio.list[value]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:program];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[self.player pause];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: The problem appeared to be, you are fetching audio stream synchronously, can you not fetch the stream asynchronously?

Comment: I see how you're thinking about it, but unfortunately, NSData doesn't have that capability. NSData represents a fixed-size block of memory. You're asking it to store a steam which could last forever!  It's hanging because it's waiting until forever to see how long the data stream will be.  You'll need a mechanism which can capture the stream in pieces -- say, one second at a time -- and save those pieces one at a time.  Starting point: http://vombat.tumblr.com/post/86294492874/caching-audio-streamed-using-avplayer

Comment: +1 for @AnnaDickinson's comment, but *NSMutableData* has that capability. I've included some pertinent info about NSURLConnection in my answer below to suggest how you can store portions of your streaming data in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose of your `data` object is to capture a portion of the audio stream, first remove this line entirely:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

As Anna Dickinson wrote in her comment, "`NSData` represents a fixed-size block of memory" and since your data isn't fixed in this case, you'll have to store your data *mutably* instead.

In order to capture portions of the streaming audio data from the internet, do so separate of your `AVPlayer` stream, and use the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods instead to receive the data incrementally and asynchronously, for example:

```
   ...

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                      timeoutInterval:30];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                   delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
                  forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
}

// Initialize the `data` here and store it as a mutable variable
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    data = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)_data {
    [data appendData:_data];

    // ** Potentially insert code here to save as you go ** 
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)_connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self finish];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)_connection destinationURL:(NSURL *) destinationURL {
    [self finish];
}

- (void)finish {
    // Do whatever you want with the data
}
```

And [according to Apple's URL loading system programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html), one nice thing about using an NSURLConnection, is that you can cancel the data stream at any time before `connectionDidFinishDownloading:` is called so you can technically save as you go then cut off the stream and thus only save a portion of the audio by using `[connection cancel];`. You can find more general info about [`NSURLConnection` in the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html)

Comment: It works, but I'm dealing with another problem. From this method im getting a NSData file, but how can I convert this data to get something like an array of samples?

Comment: @BłażejChwiećko Do you mean you'd like to have an array of NSData objects or an array of something like MP3s? Because you can't have an array of MP3s. You can only have an array of NSData objects containing the data of these samples.

Comment: @BłażejChwiećko And I don't know how you'd like to break up your array, but if, for example, you'd like to have each bit of data returned from `didReceiveData:` placed in a separate index of your array, you can remove `data = [NSMutableData data];` in `didReceiveResponse:` and replace it with `data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` then replace `[data appendData:_data];` in `didReceiveData:` with `[data addObject:_data];`.

Comment: I'm working on a simple app with sound analysis. I need to load the data from URL into an array. In array, each index has to contain a value of each sample in audio signal. After I get it like this I have to some math (like i wrote here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761417/ios-divide-audio-from-url-into-frames)  ). I'm working on it for more than a month and I'm stuck.